# How to hide element label by element id in CSS?

Tags: css, input, label

Let's say I've got this code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="foo" type="text"></td>
        <td><label for="foo">This is foo</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will hide the input:

```css
#foo { display: none;}  /* or hidden could work too, i guesss */
```

How do I hide the label?

Comment: thanks for all your comments.  I should have mentioned that I cannot change the HTML because it is proprietary software.  Only the CSS is under my control.

Therefore, the [for="foo"] approach seems best.  But it should be noted that it doesn't work in IE 6 *or* IE 7.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you give the label an ID, like this:

```
<label for="foo" id="foo_label">
```

Then this would work:

```
#foo_label { display: none;}
```

Your other options aren't really cross-browser friendly, unless javascript is an option.  The CSS3 selector, not as widely supported looks like this:

```
[for="foo"] { display: none;}
```

Answer (score 17):

Despite other answers here, you should *not* use `display:none` to hide the label element.

The accessible way to hide a label visually is to use an 'off-left' or 'clip' rule in your CSS. Using `display:none` will prevent people who use screen-readers from having access to the content of the label element. Using display:none hides content from *all* users, and that includes screen-reader users (who benefit most from label elements).

```
label[for="foo"] { 
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
```

The [W3C and WAI](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/#note-on-hiding-elements) offer more guidance on this topic, including CSS for the 'clip' technique.

Comment: best answer here

Comment: this should be the right answer. simply display:none; defeats the purpose of labels.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't care about IE6 users, use the [equality attribute selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770069(v=VS.85).aspx).

```
label[for="foo"] { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 7):

Without a class or an id, and with your specific html:

```
table tr td label {display:none}
```

Otherwise if you have jQuery

```
$('label[for="foo"]').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a separate id to the label too.

```
<label for="foo" id="foo_label">text</label>

#foo_label {display: none;}
```

Or hide the whole row

```
<tr id="foo_row">/***/</tr>

#foo_row {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give your `<tr>` tag an id `foo_row` or whatever. And hide that instead

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to add a class/id to  and then make another CSS declaration that hides it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me.

```
#_account_id{
        display: none;
    }
    label[for="_account_id"] { display: none !important; }
```