# What are the possible ways to hide an element via CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to hide an HTML element with CSS.

```
<select id="tinynav1" class="tinynav tinynav1">
```

but it's very resilient, even with the Google Inspect element I cannot change the styling.

Comment: -1 because when I google 'hide element css' this was the first result: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp and there is also a other that goes to stackoverflow so this can also be seen as a dublicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694683/how-to-hide-element-label-by-element-id-in-css/2694700#2694700

Comment: This is incredibly simple. `display:none`. I can't believe you won't have tried that already though. If there really is a bigger issue here that justifies your "very resiliant" remark, then please provide more evidence, perhaps a fiddle example that demonstrates it so we can see what you mean, because the way you've asked the question, all we can do is suggest `display:none`, which is so obvious it's hardly worth posting.

Comment: It wasn't working for me, either. Come to find out, it was because I had class="class1" class="class2" instead of class="class1 class2". I imagine that seems painfully basic to most, but it's what I missed. Hoping this can save someone from a couple hours' frustration.

Answer (score 49):

It's simple, just set the `display` property to `none` in CSS:

```
#tinynav1
{
  display:none
}
```

again when you would like to show it set the `display` to `block`.

**`visibility: hidden`** hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout.

**`display: none`** removes the element completely from the document. It does not take up any space, even though the HTML for it is still in the source code.

Other advantages of using `display`:

**`display:none`** means that the element in question will not appear on the page at all (although you can still interact with it through the DOM).  There will be no space allocated for it between the other elements.
**`visibility:hidden`** means that unlike `display:none`, the element is not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page.

Answer (score 7):

use `display:none;` or `visibility:hidden;`

Comment: @danrhul `visibility:hidden` also preserves the space it occupies, with the added bonus of the element not participating in events & tab order

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```css
select#tinynav1  { display: none; }
```

or if multiple selects should be hidden, use the corresponding class:

```css
select.tinynav1  { display: none; }
```

As inline-style you could do it also (which you can try for inspector):

```
<select id="tinynav1" style="display: none">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`,  based on your requirements:

```css
#tinynav{display:none;}
```

or

```css
 #tinynav{visibility:hidden;}
```

Refer the below URL for better understanding of `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`.

[Difference between "display:none" and "visibility:hidden"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide it and collapse the space it would need, use `display: none;` if you want to keep the space, use `visibility: hidden`.

```
<select id="tinynav1" class="tinynav tinynav1">
```

CSS

```
.tinynav {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS

```
.tinynav {
    display: none;
}
```

or

```
.tinynav {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The difference is that the former will make the `select` not rendered at all and the latter will make the `select` rendered (it will take the space of the document) but it will be completely invisible;

Here's a fiddle to show the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/rdGgn/2/
You should notice an empty space before the text in third line. It is the select that is rendered but not visible. There is no space before the second line of text, because the select is'nt rendered at all (it has `display:none`).

There is also a third option which is

```
.tinynav {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

It behaves almost the same as `visibility: hidden` but the only difference is that with `opacity: 0` you can still click the select. With `visibility: hidden` it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use `style="display:none"` directly on the `<select>` or create a css class having that setting and assign the class to the `<select>`.