# Hide button if not intended view in web - Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have asked about this question before this but no response. So I will try to ask again the question. I have this two buttons in form and I want to display those buttons in view. One button called "Close Active" and another one is "Close Draft".

So for button "Close Active", I want to show the button only in view with document status of "Active" and "Lock" while for button "Close Draft", I want to show the button only in view with document status of "Draft". I try using hide-when but it did not display.

For "Close Draft"

```
!(PStatus = "Draft")
```

For "Close Active"

```
(Pstatus != "Active" : "Lock")
```

I know how to hide-when this button in Lotus Notes, but I can't found any example of hide button for web. Any help I appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of (Pstatus != "Acitve" : "Lock"), try ! (PStatus = "Active" : "Lock");

Comment: Hide when on the web is the same as hide-when on the client.  In addition, on the web you can hide using CSS.

Comment: Hi @Duston , how can I hide using CSS?

Comment: Hi @RichardSchwartz , I try it but it show both button when display it.

Comment: Nevermind, @RichardSchwartz suggestion is right. I will update in answer.

Comment: To hide with CSS, use JavaScript like any other web element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400139/how-to-hide-an-html-element-with-css  You can also use jQuery.  
$( ".target" ).hide();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on @RichardSchwartz suggestion, I fixed the problem after test it in Lotus Notes.
I just need to move exclamation sign to front like this:

```
!(PStatus = "Active" : "Lock");
```