# How to hide any content using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I want to hide some content using CSS code. Can you guys tell me how to hide any div tag or span tag using CSS stylesheet?

Comment: if you want to add .your class or tag {display:none;}

Comment: feels more like an ad than a question to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Hide An HTML Element With CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400139/how-to-hide-an-html-element-with-css)

Answer (score 2):

Simply by using `display: none;` property. example 
`#selector { display: none;}` or `.selector { display: none;}`

Answer (score 1):

**display: none;**

- use this css property for the div or span element.

Answer (score 0):

> Hide any content using Css display:none property

```
#hide{
    display:none;
}
```

> You also can Hide any property using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to hide content using CSS
`display:none` and `visibility:hidden` the difference among two can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)