# I need to remove one line in WordPress site using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I'm building new website in WordPress using Elementor Pro. I have a section that is pretty limited when it comes to customization. I need to remove or change one line in the section. I know I can do it using CSS, but I'm not a programer :)
Here's a part of the code. I need to remove or change this "2 Responses" text.
I can place a CSS code in this section to remove it. Can you help me?

```
<div class="elementor-row">
            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-fe4d73c elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column" data-id="fe4d73c" data-element_type="column">
        <div class="elementor-column-wrap  elementor-element-populated">
                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-e84d355 elementor-widget elementor-widget-post-comments" data-id="e84d355" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="post-comments.theme_comments">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <section id="comments" class="comments-area">

        <h3 class="title-comments">
        2 Responses     </h3>

    
<ol class="comment-list">
            <li id="comment-2" class="comment even thread-even depth-1">
```

Comment: `#comments h3.title-comments { display: none }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Hide An HTML Element With CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400139/how-to-hide-an-html-element-with-css)

Comment: Thatnks! It works!