# Hiding element in body, which has specific classes

Tags: html, css

I got some code here:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Select View</title>
    </head>
    <body class="class-1 class-2 class-3 class-4 class-5 class-6">
        Many divs here
        ...
        ...
        ...
        <div id="test">
            <p>PHP code here</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I want to hide the div with the test id. My site is based on wordpress, so in css I have to refer to a specific body.
I tried:

```
body.class-1, .class-2, .class-3, .class-4, .class-5, div#test{
    color: red;
}
```

and the color is working, "PHP code here" is on red color, but when i do this:

```
body.class-1, .class-2, .class-3, .class-4, .class-5, div#test{
        display: none; //or visibility: hidden;
    }
```

all site dissapears. 
Any ideas how to hide only this div?

Comment: Why you just don't use `div#test{ display: none; }` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694683/how-to-hide-element-label-by-element-id-in-css

Comment: @ShevchenkoViktor Great Minds!!

Answer (score 3):

Just use what you have already

```
div#test{
   display: none;
}
```

When you called `body.class-1, .class-2, .class-3, .class-4, .class-5,` and set `display: none`, it is the expected behaviour, because you are hiding all elements rather than just the test div!

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't repeat the `id` in other elements you can just use,

```
#test { 
    display: none;
}
```

Just in-case if you have another element (ex: span) with the same id you have to specifically mention that you need to hide the `div element with id=test`

```
div#test { 
    display: none;
}
```

It is always a good thing to uniquely mark your elements if possible. Since you are dealing with `classes` if you just mention one class it will select the matching element.

In the below case you used your  selection is the whole body,

```
body.class-1, .class-2, .class-3, .class-4, .class-5, div#test{
    display: none; //or visibility: hidden;
}
```

This might be the same case if you just use the below code,

```
.class-1 {
    display: none; //class-1 supposed to pick the whole body here;
}
```