# Hide label class in CSS

Tags: css, label

There are two different div classes with same label class. I'm trying to hide one of the label class.

First is:

`<div class="wcfm_custom_field_display wcfm_custom_field_display_%e1%83%9b%e1%83%93%e1%83%94%e1%83%91%e1%83%90%e1%83%a0%e1%83%94%e1%83%9d%e1%83%91%e1%83%90"><h4 class="wcfm_custom_field_display_heading">მდებარეობა</h4><label class="wcfm_custom_field_display_label">მდებარეობა: </label><span class="wcfm_custom_field_display_value">თბილისი</span><br></div>`

And the second is:

`<div class="wcfm_custom_field_display wcfm_custom_field_display_%e1%83%9e%e1%83%a0%e1%83%9d%e1%83%93%e1%83%a3%e1%83%a5%e1%83%a2%e1%83%98%e1%83%a1-%e1%83%9b%e1%83%93%e1%83%92%e1%83%9d%e1%83%9b%e1%83%90%e1%83%a0%e1%83%94%e1%83%9d%e1%83%91%e1%83%90"><h4 class="wcfm_custom_field_display_heading">პროდუქტის მდგომარეობა</h4><label class="wcfm_custom_field_display_label">მდგომარეობა: </label><span class="wcfm_custom_field_display_value">მეორადი</span><br></div>`

I want to hide `wcfm_custom_field_display_label` <= this label from first div class.
So, what kind of CSS I have to write?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This answer helps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694683/how-to-hide-element-label-by-element-id-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **first-of-type** or **nth-of-type(1)**

**With first-of-type**

```
.wcfm_custom_field_display:first-of-type {
  display: none;  
}
```

**With nth-of-type(1)**

```
.wcfm_custom_field_display:nth-of-type(1) {
      display: none;  
    }
```

Comment: Oops. It doesn't work. I've tried both and both labels were hidden.

Comment: If you have any other ideas please write. Thank you.

Comment: Problem is solved. It is made from Custom JS:  ```document.querySelector("div.summary div:first-child label").style.display="none";```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
.wcfm_custom_field_display{
  display: inline; /*choose any display you want*/
}

.wcfm_custom_field_display:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can we insert div class and then label class in CSS to concrete an element?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. It is made from Custom JS:

`document.querySelector("div.summary div:first-child label").style.display="none";`